# How to integrate simple wallet on website

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, wallet-transfer

I couldn't find the answer to my question anywhere else so I'll explain it here hoping someone will answer.

I would need to integrate a pretty simple, but of course secure, wallet on my website. That wallet is not supposed to be used as a main wallet by people nor for higher sums. 
Basically, I just need to check if someone has a sufficient balance to bid on something, and if that's the fact, be able to bid. As soon as the bid runs out, it would be great to also be able to take that eth automatically (therefore, being able to freezethe ETH used to bid would be nice).

Does someone know if there is any API/Service that would be able to provide this, or how I can find a skillful developer for this (and about what time effort we're probably talking here)?

Answer (score 2):

**[Q]:** How to integrate simple wallet on website

**[A]:** Use [ETH Light Wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet#lightwallet).
Lightweight JS Wallet for Node and the browser.

> LightWallet is a HD wallet that can store your private keys encrypted in the 
>   browser to allow you to run Ethereum dapps even if you're not running
>   a local Ethereum node. It uses BIP32 and BIP39 to generate an HD tree
>   of addresses from a randomly generated 12-word seed.
>
> LightWallet is primarily intended to be a signing provider for the
>   Hooked Web3 provider through the keystore module. This allows you to
>   have full control over your private keys while still connecting to a
>   remote node to relay signed transactions. Moreover, the txutils
>   functions can be used to construct transactions when offline, for use
>   in e.g. air-gapped coldwallet implementations.

**[Q]:** Basically, I just need to check if someone has a sufficient balance to bid on something, and if that's the fact, be able to bid. As soon as the bid runs out, it would be great to also be able to take that eth automatically.

**[A]:** You can achieve this without wallet integration. Just use [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). Your users can use [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) to sign transactions.

**[Q]:** or how I can find a skillful developer for this (and about what time effort we're probably talking here)?

**[A]:** Off-topic. It depends on your project goals.